# Complete list of Greek -μι verbs

Tags: vocabulary, greek

Is there an exhaustive list somewhere of all the simplex -μι verbs in Greek?

Searching Perseus for words ending in -μι brings up a long list of results, most of which are prefixed forms of the same few verbs (e.g. ἀναδίδωμι, ἀποδίδωμι, ἐκδίδωμι etc.) It would be convenient to have a full list of attested -μι verbs excluding compounds.

Comment: Is there a particular dialect and time period you're interested in? If I'm remembering right, as Attic transformed into Koinē a bunch of -mi verbs got regularized into -ō verbs; on the flipside, Aeolic has many more -mi verbs than Attic ever did.

Comment: @Draconis Classical Attic I suppose, by default. But I'd be glad to see a complete list for any dialect or period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list is probably very close to this:

> ἄγνυμι ἄημι βίβημι δάμνημι δίδημι δίδωμι δαίνυμι δείκνυμι εἰμί εἶμι ἕννυμι εἵργνυμι ἔργνυμι ζεύγνυμι ζώννυμι ἵημι ἵλημι ἵστημι κίδνημι κίχρημι κεδάννυμι κεράννυμι κορέννυμι κρεμάννυμι κρήμνημι κτίννυμι μίγνυμι μείγνυμι οἴγνυμι ὄλλυμι ὄμνυμι ὀμόργνυμι ὀνίνημι ὀρέγνυμι ὄρνυμι πέρνημι πήγνυμι πίμπλημι πίμπρημι πίτνημι πετάννυμι ῥήγνυμι ῥώννυμι σβέννυμι σκίδνημι σκεδάννυμι στορέννυμι τίθημι φημί χρώννυμι χώννυμι

The method for finding this list is explained below.

---

Here is a brute force approach that gets us to a pretty short list.
With help from TKR who actually knows Greek unlike me, it got polished further into the final list.

Expeditio Bipes posted a now deleted answer with all verbs ending in -μι, taken from an online dictionary:

```
ἄγνυμι ἄημι ἀμφιέννυμι ἀμφίστημι ἀμφιτίθημι ἀναδείκνυμι ἀναδίδωμι ἀναζεύγνυμι ἀναζώννυμι ἀνακεράννυμι ἀνακρεμάννυμι ἀναμίγνυμι ἀναπετάννυμι ἀναπήγνυμι ἀναπίμπλημι ἀναρρήγνυμι ἀναρρώννυμι ἀνασκεδάννυμι ἀνατίθημι ἀναχώννυμι ἄνειμι ἀνεκπίμπλημι ἀνθίστημι ἀνίημι ἀνίστημι ἀνοίγνυμι ἀνόρνυμι ἀνταναπίμπλημι ἀντάνειμι ἀντανίστημι ἀνταποδείκνυμι ἀνταποδίδωμι ἀνταπόλλυμι ἀνταφίημι ἀντεκτίθημι ἀντεμπίπλημι ἀντεμπίπρημι ἀντενδίδωμι ἀντεπαφίημι ἀντέπειμι ἀντεπέξειμι ἀντεπιδείκνυμι ἀντεπιτίθημι ἀντιδίδωμι ἀντιδιέξειμι ἀντικαθίστημι ἀντιμεθίστημι ἀντιμέτειμι ἀντιπαρατίθημι ἀντιπάρειμι ἀντιπρόειμι ἀντιπρόσειμι ἀντιτίθημι ἀντίφημι ἀντόμνυμι ἀπανίστημι ἄπειμι ἄπειμι ἀποδείκνυμι ἀποδίδωμι ἀποκαθίστημι ἀποκρεμάννυμι ἀποκτίννυμι ἀπόλλυμι ἀπόμνυμι ἀπομόργνυμι ἀποπήγνυμι ἀποπίμπλημι ἀποπροΐημι ἀπόρνυμι ἀπορρήγνυμι ἀποσβέννυμι ἀποσκεδάννυμι ἀποτίθημι ἀπόφημι ἀποφράγνυμι ἀποχώννυμι ἀφίημι ἀφίστημι βίβημι δαίνυμι δάμνημι δείκνυμι διαδείκνυμι διαδίδωμι διαζώννυμι διάημι διακίχρημι διαμεθίημι διαπήγνυμι διαρρήγνυμι διασκεδάννυμι διασκίδνημι διατίθημι διαφίημι διαφράγνυμι δίδημι δίδωμι δίειμι διέξειμι διεξίημι διίημι διίστημι διοίγνυμι διόλλυμι διόμνυμι ἐγκαθίημι ἐγκαθίστημι ἐγκαταπήγνυμι ἐγκαταζεύγνυμι ἐγκεράννυμι εἶμι εἵργνυμι εἰσάνειμι εἰσαφίημι εἰσδίδωμι εἴσειμι εἰσέργνυμι εἰσίημι εἰστίθημι ἐκδείκνυμι ἐκδίδωμι ἐκκρεμάννυμι ἐκπερίειμι ἐκπετάννυμι ἐκπίμπλημι ἐκπροίημι ἐκρήγνυμι ἐκσκεδάννυμι ἐκτίθημι ἔκφημι ἐμπετάννυμι ἐμπήγνυμι ἐμπίπλημι ἐμπίμπρημι ἐναφίημι ἐνδείκνυμι ἐνδίδωμι ἐνδίημι ἔνειμι ἐνζεύγνυμι ἐνίημι ἐνίστημι ἕννυμι ἐνόρνυμι ἐντίθημι ἐξάγνυμι ἐξάνειμι ἐξανίημι ἐξανίστημι ἐξαπόλλυμι ἐξαφίημι ἔξειμι ἐξεφίημι ἐξίημι ἐξίστημι ἐξόλλυμι ἐξόμνυμι ἐξομόργνυμι ἐξυπανίστημι ἐπάγνυμι ἐπαναρρήγνυμι ἐπανατίθημι ἐπάνειμι ἐπανίημι ἐπανίστημι ἐπαφίημι ἔπειμι ἔπειμι ἐπείσειμι ἐπενδίδωμι ἐπέξειμι ἐπιδείκνυμι ἐπιδίδωμι ἐπιέννυμι ἐπιζεύγνυμι ἐπιζώννυμι ἐπικάτειμι ἐπικεράννυμι ἐπικίδνημι ἐπικίχρημι ἐπικρεμάννυμι ἐπιμίγνυμι ἐπιπάρειμι ἐπιπάρειμι ἐπιπετάννυμι ἐπιπήγνυμι ἐπιπίμπλημι ἐπιπροίημι ἐπιρρήγνυμι ἐπιρρώννυμι ἐπισκεδάννυμι ἐπιστορέννυμι ἐπισυνδίδωμι ἐπιτίθημι ἐπιχρώννυμι ἐπόμνυμι ἐπόρνυμι ἔργνυμι ἐφίημι ἐφίστημι ζεύγνυμι ζώννυμι ἠρεμί ἵημι ἵλημι ἵστημι καθείργνυμι καθέννυμι καθίημι καθίστημι καθυφίημι κατάγνυμι καταδείκνυμι καταδίδωμι καταέννυμι καταζεύγνυμι καταζώννυμι κατακρεμάννυμι καταμίγνυμι καταπετάννυμι καταπήγνυμι καταπίμπλημι καταπίμπρημι καταπροδίδωμι καταρρήγνυμι κατασβέννυμι κατασκεδάννυμι καταστρώννυμι κατατίθημι κατάφημι καταφίημι καταχώννυμι κάτειμι κατείργνυμι κατεμπίπρημι κατόλλυμι κατόμνυμι κεδάννυμι κεράννυμι κίχρημι κόμμι κορέννυμι κρεμάννυμι κρήμνημι μεθίημι μεθίστημι μεταδίδωμι μεταζεύγνυμι μεταμίγνυμι μετανίστημι μετατίθημι μετάφημι μέτειμι μέτειμι μετεκδίδωμι μετεντίθημι μίγνυμι ὄλλυμι ὄμνυμι ὀμόργνυμι ὀνίνημι ὀρέγνυμι ὄρνυμι παραδείκνυμι παραδίδωμι παραζεύγνυμι παραζώννυμι παρακαθίημι παρακαθίστημι παρακαταπήγνυμι παρακρεμάννυμι παραμίγνυμι παρανίστημι παρανοίγνυμι παραπήγνυμι παραπόλλυμι παραρρήγνυμι παραστορέννυμι παρατίθημι παράφημι παραχρώννυμι παραχώννυμι πάρειμι πάρειμι παρεμπίπλημι παρέξειμι παρεξίημι παρίημι παρίστημι παροίγνυμι περιάγνυμι περίειμι περίειμι περιέννυμι περιίστημι περικαταρρήγνυμι περικρεμάννυμι περιπετάννυμι περιπήγνυμι περιπίμπρημι περιρρήγνυμι περιτίθημι πέρνημι πετάννυμι πήγνυμι πίμπλημι πίμπρημι πίτνημι προάγνυμι προάπειμι προαποδείκνυμι προδείκνυμι προδίδωμι πρόειμι πρόειμι προέξειμι προεπαφίημι προίημι προίστημι προκαθίημι προκαθίστημι προμίγνυμι προόμνυμι προπετάννυμι προσαμφιέννυμι προσαναρρήγνυμι προσαποδείκνυμι προσαποδίδωμι προσαπόλλυμι προσαφίστημι προσδίδωμι πρόσειμι πρόσειμι προσεπιτίθημι προσίημι προσίστημι προσκαθίστημι προσκατατίθημι προσμείγνυμι προσόμνυμι προσομόργνυμι προσπαρατίθημι προσπήγνυμι προσρήγνυμι προστίθημι πρόσφημι προσχώννυμι προτίθημι ῥήγνυμι ῥώννυμι σβέννυμι σκεδάννυμι σκίδνημι στορέννυμι συγκαθίημι συγκαθίστημι συγκαταζεύγνυμι συγκαταμίγνυμι συγκαταπίμπλημι συγκατατίθημι συγκεράννυμι συγχώννυμι συζεύγνυμι συμμεθίστημι συμμίγνυμι συμπαρατίθημι συμπάρειμι συμπάρειμι συμπαρίστημι συμπερίειμι συμπήγνυμι σύμφημι συνάγνυμι συναναδίδωμι συναναζεύγνυμι συναναμίγνυμι συνανατίθημι συνανίστημι συναπόλλυμι συναπορρήγνυμι συναποσβέννυμι συναφίστημι συνδαίνυμι συνδιέξειμι σύνειμι σύνειμι συνείργνυμι συνεκδίδωμι συνεμπίπρημι συνενδίδωμι συνεξανίστημι συνέξειμι συνεπανίστημι συνέπειμι συνεπιδείκνυμι συνεπιρρώννυμι συνεπιτίθημι συνεπόμνυμι συνεφίστημι συνίημι συνίστημι συνόλλυμι συνόμνυμι συντίθημι συνυποδείκνυμι συρρήγνυμι συσκεδάννυμι τίθημι ὑπάνειμι ὑπανίημι ὑπάπειμι ὕπειμι ὕπειμι ὑπενδίδωμι ὑπέξειμι ὑπερεμπίπλημι ὑπερίημι ὑπερκορέννυμι ὑπερκρεμάννυμι ὑπερπετάννυμι ὑπερπίμπλημι ὑπερτίθημι ὑποδείκνυμι ὑποδίδωμι ὑποζεύγνυμι ὑποζώννυμι ὑπομίγνυμι ὑποπετάννυμι ὑποπίμπλημι ὑποπίμπρημι ὑπόρνυμι ὑπορρήγνυμι ὑποστορέννυμι ὑποτίθημι ὑφίημι ὑφίστημι φημί χώννυμι
```

This list has a whole lot of prefixes.
To make finding and removing them easier, I ordered the list from the end of the word, so that all words with the same ending become consecutive.
My quick code was not good with diacritics, so the unprefixed versions can appear far from the prefixed ones, but that is only a minor nuisance.
(Let me know if you want the code. It was HTML+JS, so it can be used through a browser.)
Here is the reordered list:

```
ἠρεμί φημί ἀποπροΐημι διάημι ἐνδίημι καθίημι παρακαθίημι συγκαθίημι ἐγκαθίημι προκαθίημι μεθίημι διαμεθίημι διίημι ἐξανίημι ἐπανίημι ὑπανίημι συνίημι ἀνίημι ἐνίημι διεξίημι παρεξίημι ἐξίημι προίημι ἐπιπροίημι ἐκπροίημι παρίημι ὑπερίημι προσίημι εἰσίημι διαφίημι ἐναφίημι ἐξαφίημι προεπαφίημι ἀντεπαφίημι ἐπαφίημι εἰσαφίημι καταφίημι ἀνταφίημι ἐξεφίημι καθυφίημι ἀφίημι ἐφίημι ὑφίημι βίβημι δίδημι τίθημι διατίθημι συνανατίθημι ἐπανατίθημι ἀνατίθημι παρατίθημι ἀντιπαρατίθημι συμπαρατίθημι προσπαρατίθημι κατατίθημι συγκατατίθημι προσκατατίθημι μετατίθημι συνεπιτίθημι προσεπιτίθημι ἀντεπιτίθημι ἐπιτίθημι περιτίθημι ἀντιτίθημι ἀμφιτίθημι ἀντεκτίθημι ἐκτίθημι μετεντίθημι συντίθημι ἐντίθημι ἀποτίθημι ὑποτίθημι προτίθημι ὑπερτίθημι προστίθημι εἰστίθημι παρεμπίπλημι ὑπερεμπίπλημι ἀντεμπίπλημι ἐμπίπλημι πίμπλημι ἀνταναπίμπλημι ἀναπίμπλημι καταπίμπλημι συγκαταπίμπλημι ἐπιπίμπλημι ἀνεκπίμπλημι ἐκπίμπλημι ἀποπίμπλημι ὑποπίμπλημι ὑπερπίμπλημι ἵλημι ὀνίνημι ἐπικίδνημι σκίδνημι διασκίδνημι δάμνημι κρήμνημι πέρνημι πίτνημι συνεμπίπρημι κατεμπίπρημι ἀντεμπίπρημι πίμπρημι καταπίμπρημι περιπίμπρημι ἐμπίμπρημι ὑποπίμπρημι κίχρημι διακίχρημι ἐπικίχρημι καθίστημι παρακαθίστημι συγκαθίστημι ἐγκαθίστημι ἀντικαθίστημι ἀποκαθίστημι προκαθίστημι προσκαθίστημι μεθίστημι ἀντιμεθίστημι συμμεθίστημι ἀνθίστημι διίστημι περιίστημι συνανίστημι συνεξανίστημι ἐξανίστημι συνεπανίστημι ἐξυπανίστημι ἀπανίστημι ἐπανίστημι παρανίστημι μετανίστημι ἀντανίστημι συνίστημι ἀνίστημι ἐνίστημι ἐξίστημι προίστημι παρίστημι συμπαρίστημι προσίστημι συναφίστημι προσαφίστημι συνεφίστημι ἀμφίστημι ἀφίστημι ἐφίστημι ὑφίστημι ἵστημι παράφημι κατάφημι μετάφημι ἀντίφημι ἔκφημι σύμφημι πρόσφημι ἀπόφημι ἄημι ἵημι δίειμι περίειμι περίειμι ἐκπερίειμι συμπερίειμι ἐξάνειμι ἐπάνειμι ὑπάνειμι εἰσάνειμι ἀντάνειμι σύνειμι σύνειμι ἄνειμι ἔνειμι διέξειμι ἀντιδιέξειμι συνδιέξειμι συνέξειμι προέξειμι ἀντεπέξειμι ἐπέξειμι ὑπέξειμι παρέξειμι ἔξειμι προάπειμι ὑπάπειμι συνέπειμι ἀντέπειμι ἄπειμι ἄπειμι ἔπειμι ἔπειμι ὕπειμι ὕπειμι πάρειμι πάρειμι ἐπιπάρειμι ἐπιπάρειμι ἀντιπάρειμι συμπάρειμι συμπάρειμι ἐπείσειμι πρόσειμι πρόσειμι ἀντιπρόσειμι εἴσειμι κάτειμι ἐπικάτειμι μέτειμι μέτειμι ἀντιμέτειμι πρόειμι πρόειμι ἀντιπρόειμι κόμμι διόλλυμι συνόλλυμι ἐξόλλυμι συναπόλλυμι ἐξαπόλλυμι παραπόλλυμι προσαπόλλυμι ἀνταπόλλυμι ἀπόλλυμι κατόλλυμι ὄλλυμι δαίνυμι συνδαίνυμι περιάγνυμι συνάγνυμι ἐξάγνυμι προάγνυμι ἐπάγνυμι διαφράγνυμι ἀποφράγνυμι κατάγνυμι ὀρέγνυμι πήγνυμι διαπήγνυμι ἀναπήγνυμι παραπήγνυμι καταπήγνυμι παρακαταπήγνυμι ἐγκαταπήγνυμι ἐπιπήγνυμι περιπήγνυμι συμπήγνυμι ἐμπήγνυμι ἀποπήγνυμι προσπήγνυμι ἐκρήγνυμι διαρρήγνυμι ἐπαναρρήγνυμι προσαναρρήγνυμι ἀναρρήγνυμι παραρρήγνυμι καταρρήγνυμι περικαταρρήγνυμι ἐπιρρήγνυμι περιρρήγνυμι συναπορρήγνυμι ἀπορρήγνυμι ὑπορρήγνυμι συρρήγνυμι προσρήγνυμι ῥήγνυμι προσμείγνυμι μίγνυμι συναναμίγνυμι ἀναμίγνυμι παραμίγνυμι καταμίγνυμι συγκαταμίγνυμι μεταμίγνυμι ἐπιμίγνυμι συμμίγνυμι ὑπομίγνυμι προμίγνυμι διοίγνυμι παρανοίγνυμι ἀνοίγνυμι παροίγνυμι εἰσέργνυμι καθείργνυμι συνείργνυμι κατείργνυμι ἐξομόργνυμι ἀπομόργνυμι προσομόργνυμι ὀμόργνυμι ἔργνυμι εἵργνυμι ζεύγνυμι συναναζεύγνυμι ἀναζεύγνυμι παραζεύγνυμι καταζεύγνυμι συγκαταζεύγνυμι ἐγκαταζεύγνυμι μεταζεύγνυμι ἐπιζεύγνυμι ἐνζεύγνυμι ὑποζεύγνυμι συζεύγνυμι ἄγνυμι δείκνυμι διαδείκνυμι ἀναδείκνυμι παραδείκνυμι καταδείκνυμι συνεπιδείκνυμι ἀντεπιδείκνυμι ἐπιδείκνυμι ἐκδείκνυμι ἐνδείκνυμι προαποδείκνυμι προσαποδείκνυμι ἀνταποδείκνυμι συνυποδείκνυμι ἀποδείκνυμι ὑποδείκνυμι προδείκνυμι διόμνυμι συνόμνυμι ἐξόμνυμι προόμνυμι συνεπόμνυμι ἀπόμνυμι ἐπόμνυμι προσόμνυμι κατόμνυμι ἀντόμνυμι ὄμνυμι κεδάννυμι σκεδάννυμι διασκεδάννυμι ἀνασκεδάννυμι κατασκεδάννυμι ἐπισκεδάννυμι ἐκσκεδάννυμι ἀποσκεδάννυμι συσκεδάννυμι κρεμάννυμι ἀνακρεμάννυμι παρακρεμάννυμι κατακρεμάννυμι ἐπικρεμάννυμι περικρεμάννυμι ἐκκρεμάννυμι ἀποκρεμάννυμι ὑπερκρεμάννυμι κεράννυμι ἀνακεράννυμι συγκεράννυμι ἐγκεράννυμι ἐπικεράννυμι πετάννυμι ἀναπετάννυμι καταπετάννυμι ἐπιπετάννυμι περιπετάννυμι ἐκπετάννυμι ἐμπετάννυμι ὑποπετάννυμι προπετάννυμι ὑπερπετάννυμι καταέννυμι σβέννυμι κατασβέννυμι συναποσβέννυμι ἀποσβέννυμι καθέννυμι ἐπιέννυμι περιέννυμι προσαμφιέννυμι ἀμφιέννυμι κορέννυμι ὑπερκορέννυμι στορέννυμι παραστορέννυμι ἐπιστορέννυμι ὑποστορέννυμι ἀποκτίννυμι ζώννυμι διαζώννυμι ἀναζώννυμι παραζώννυμι καταζώννυμι ἐπιζώννυμι ὑποζώννυμι ἀναρρώννυμι συνεπιρρώννυμι ἐπιρρώννυμι καταστρώννυμι παραχρώννυμι ἐπιχρώννυμι χώννυμι ἀναχώννυμι παραχώννυμι καταχώννυμι συγχώννυμι ἀποχώννυμι προσχώννυμι ῥώννυμι ἕννυμι ἀνόρνυμι ἐνόρνυμι ἀπόρνυμι ἐπόρνυμι ὑπόρνυμι ὄρνυμι δίδωμι διαδίδωμι συναναδίδωμι ἀναδίδωμι παραδίδωμι καταδίδωμι μεταδίδωμι ἐπιδίδωμι ἀντιδίδωμι συνεκδίδωμι μετεκδίδωμι ἐκδίδωμι συνενδίδωμι ἐπενδίδωμι ὑπενδίδωμι ἀντενδίδωμι ἐπισυνδίδωμι ἐνδίδωμι προσαποδίδωμι ἀνταποδίδωμι ἀποδίδωμι ὑποδίδωμι προδίδωμι καταπροδίδωμι προσδίδωμι εἰσδίδωμι εἶμι
```

From here we can start picking out clearly repeated patterns, shrinking the list to:

```
ἠρεμί φημί βίβημι δίδημι τίθημι πίμπλημι ἵλημι ὀνίνημι δάμνημι κρήμνημι πέρνημι πίτνημι πίμπρημι κίχρημι ἵστημι ἄημι ἵημι κόμμι ὄλλυμι δαίνυμι ὀρέγνυμι πήγνυμι ῥήγνυμι μίγνυμι ὀμόργνυμι ἔργνυμι εἵργνυμι ζεύγνυμι δείκνυμι ὄμνυμι κρεμάννυμι κεράννυμι ζώννυμι ῥώννυμι ὄρνυμι δίδωμι εἶμι
```

These words left me a little confused about the number of underlying verbs, not knowing much Greek:

```
ἐπικίδνημι σκίδνημι διασκίδνημι
πετάννυμι σβέννυμι ὑπερκορέννυμι στορέννυμι ἕννυμι
διοίγνυμι παρανοίγνυμι ἀνοίγνυμι παροίγνυμι
διαφράγνυμι ἀποφράγνυμι ἄγνυμι
παραχρώννυμι ἐπιχρώννυμι χώννυμι
κεδάννυμι σκεδάννυμι
ἀποκτίννυμι
προσμείγνυμι
```

The leftovers from this process grouped by the simplex verb:

```
ἐνδίημι καθίημι παρακαθίημι συγκαθίημι ἐγκαθίημι προκαθίημι μεθίημι διαμεθίημι διίημι ἐξανίημι ἐπανίημι ὑπανίημι συνίημι ἀνίημι ἐνίημι διεξίημι παρεξίημι ἐξίημι προίημι ἐπιπροίημι ἐκπροίημι παρίημι ὑπερίημι προσίημι εἰσίημι διαφίημι ἐναφίημι ἐξαφίημι προεπαφίημι ἀντεπαφίημι ἐπαφίημι εἰσαφίημι καταφίημι ἀνταφίημι ἐξεφίημι καθυφίημι ἀφίημι ἐφίημι ὑφίημι ἀποπροΐημι
διατίθημι συνανατίθημι ἐπανατίθημι ἀνατίθημι παρατίθημι ἀντιπαρατίθημι συμπαρατίθημι προσπαρατίθημι κατατίθημι συγκατατίθημι προσκατατίθημι μετατίθημι συνεπιτίθημι προσεπιτίθημι ἀντεπιτίθημι ἐπιτίθημι περιτίθημι ἀντιτίθημι ἀμφιτίθημι ἀντεκτίθημι ἐκτίθημι μετεντίθημι συντίθημι ἐντίθημι ἀποτίθημι ὑποτίθημι προτίθημι ὑπερτίθημι προστίθημι εἰστίθημι
διαδείκνυμι ἀναδείκνυμι παραδείκνυμι καταδείκνυμι συνεπιδείκνυμι ἀντεπιδείκνυμι ἐπιδείκνυμι ἐκδείκνυμι ἐνδείκνυμι προαποδείκνυμι προσαποδείκνυμι ἀνταποδείκνυμι συνυποδείκνυμι ἀποδείκνυμι ὑποδείκνυμι προδείκνυμι
διαδίδωμι συναναδίδωμι ἀναδίδωμι παραδίδωμι καταδίδωμι μεταδίδωμι ἐπιδίδωμι ἀντιδίδωμι συνεκδίδωμι μετεκδίδωμι ἐκδίδωμι συνενδίδωμι ἐπενδίδωμι ὑπενδίδωμι ἀντενδίδωμι ἐπισυνδίδωμι ἐνδίδωμι προσαποδίδωμι ἀνταποδίδωμι ἀποδίδωμι ὑποδίδωμι προδίδωμι καταπροδίδωμι προσδίδωμι εἰσδίδωμι
δίειμι περίειμι περίειμι ἐκπερίειμι συμπερίειμι ἐξάνειμι ἐπάνειμι ὑπάνειμι εἰσάνειμι ἀντάνειμι σύνειμι σύνειμι ἄνειμι ἔνειμι διέξειμι ἀντιδιέξειμι συνδιέξειμι συνέξειμι προέξειμι ἀντεπέξειμι ἐπέξειμι ὑπέξειμι παρέξειμι ἔξειμι προάπειμι ὑπάπειμι συνέπειμι ἀντέπειμι ἄπειμι ἄπειμι ἔπειμι ἔπειμι ὕπειμι ὕπειμι πάρειμι πάρειμι ἐπιπάρειμι ἐπιπάρειμι ἀντιπάρειμι συμπάρειμι συμπάρειμι ἐπείσειμι πρόσειμι πρόσειμι ἀντιπρόσειμι εἴσειμι κάτειμι ἐπικάτειμι μέτειμι μέτειμι ἀντιμέτειμι πρόειμι πρόειμι ἀντιπρόειμι
καθίστημι παρακαθίστημι συγκαθίστημι ἐγκαθίστημι ἀντικαθίστημι ἀποκαθίστημι προκαθίστημι προσκαθίστημι μεθίστημι ἀντιμεθίστημι συμμεθίστημι ἀνθίστημι διίστημι περιίστημι συνανίστημι συνεξανίστημι ἐξανίστημι συνεπανίστημι ἐξυπανίστημι ἀπανίστημι ἐπανίστημι παρανίστημι μετανίστημι ἀντανίστημι συνίστημι ἀνίστημι ἐνίστημι ἐξίστημι προίστημι παρίστημι συμπαρίστημι προσίστημι συναφίστημι προσαφίστημι συνεφίστημι ἀμφίστημι ἀφίστημι ἐφίστημι ὑφίστημι
παράφημι κατάφημι μετάφημι ἀντίφημι ἔκφημι σύμφημι πρόσφημι ἀπόφημι
συναναμίγνυμι ἀναμίγνυμι παραμίγνυμι καταμίγνυμι συγκαταμίγνυμι μεταμίγνυμι ἐπιμίγνυμι συμμίγνυμι ὑπομίγνυμι προμίγνυμι
διακίχρημι ἐπικίχρημι
διαζώννυμι ἀναζώννυμι παραζώννυμι καταζώννυμι ἐπιζώννυμι ὑποζώννυμι
παρεμπίπλημι ὑπερεμπίπλημι ἀντεμπίπλημι ἐμπίπλημι  ἀνταναπίμπλημι ἀναπίμπλημι καταπίμπλημι συγκαταπίμπλημι ἐπιπίμπλημι ἀνεκπίμπλημι ἐκπίμπλημι ἀποπίμπλημι ὑποπίμπλημι ὑπερπίμπλημι
ἀναπετάννυμι καταπετάννυμι ἐπιπετάννυμι περιπετάννυμι ἐκπετάννυμι ἐμπετάννυμι ὑποπετάννυμι προπετάννυμι ὑπερπετάννυμι
συναναζεύγνυμι ἀναζεύγνυμι παραζεύγνυμι καταζεύγνυμι συγκαταζεύγνυμι ἐγκαταζεύγνυμι μεταζεύγνυμι ἐπιζεύγνυμι ἐνζεύγνυμι ὑποζεύγνυμι συζεύγνυμι
κατασβέννυμι συναποσβέννυμι ἀποσβέννυμι
καταέννυμι καθέννυμι ἐπιέννυμι περιέννυμι προσαμφιέννυμι ἀμφιέννυμι κορέννυμι
παραστορέννυμι ἐπιστορέννυμι ὑποστορέννυμι
διαπήγνυμι ἀναπήγνυμι παραπήγνυμι καταπήγνυμι παρακαταπήγνυμι ἐγκαταπήγνυμι ἐπιπήγνυμι περιπήγνυμι συμπήγνυμι ἐμπήγνυμι ἀποπήγνυμι προσπήγνυμι
ἐκρήγνυμι διαρρήγνυμι ἐπαναρρήγνυμι προσαναρρήγνυμι ἀναρρήγνυμι παραρρήγνυμι καταρρήγνυμι περικαταρρήγνυμι ἐπιρρήγνυμι περιρρήγνυμι συναπορρήγνυμι ἀπορρήγνυμι ὑπορρήγνυμι συρρήγνυμι προσρήγνυμι
περιάγνυμι συνάγνυμι ἐξάγνυμι προάγνυμι ἐπάγνυμι κατάγνυμι
διασκεδάννυμι ἀνασκεδάννυμι κατασκεδάννυμι ἐπισκεδάννυμι ἐκσκεδάννυμι ἀποσκεδάννυμι συσκεδάννυμι
διόμνυμι συνόμνυμι ἐξόμνυμι προόμνυμι συνεπόμνυμι ἀπόμνυμι ἐπόμνυμι προσόμνυμι κατόμνυμι ἀντόμνυμι
καταπίμπρημι περιπίμπρημι ἐμπίμπρημι ὑποπίμπρημι
(with preceding ones?) συνεμπίπρημι κατεμπίπρημι ἀντεμπίπρημι
διόλλυμι συνόλλυμι ἐξόλλυμι συναπόλλυμι ἐξαπόλλυμι παραπόλλυμι προσαπόλλυμι ἀνταπόλλυμι ἀπόλλυμι κατόλλυμι
ἀνακεράννυμι συγκεράννυμι ἐγκεράννυμι ἐπικεράννυμι
ἀνακρεμάννυμι παρακρεμάννυμι κατακρεμάννυμι ἐπικρεμάννυμι περικρεμάννυμι ἐκκρεμάννυμι ἀποκρεμάννυμι ὑπερκρεμάννυμι
ἀνόρνυμι ἐνόρνυμι ἀπόρνυμι ἐπόρνυμι ὑπόρνυμι
ἀναχώννυμι παραχώννυμι καταχώννυμι συγχώννυμι ἀποχώννυμι προσχώννυμι
ἐξομόργνυμι ἀπομόργνυμι προσομόργνυμι
(?) ἀναρρώννυμι συνεπιρρώννυμι ἐπιρρώννυμι καταστρώννυμι
(?) εἰσέργνυμι καθείργνυμι συνείργνυμι κατείργνυμι
συνδαίνυμι
διάημι
```

To help me further, TKR pointed out in comments that:

- The simplex verbs on the second list are: σκίδνημι πετάννυμι σβέννυμι στορέννυμι ἕννυμι ἄγνυμι χώννυμι κεδάννυμι σκεδάννυμι.
- In the same list there are some compound verbs of which the simplex forms don't seem to appear in the master list for some reason: κίδνημι κορέννυμι οἴγνυμι χρώννυμι κτίννυμι μείγνυμι.
- Also εἰμί (not the same as εἶμι) is missing. [Joonas' guess: these were somehow conflated by the search system that generated the initial list.]
- A couple false positives: κόμμι is not a verb but a noun meaning "gum", and ἠρεμί is an adverb "gently".

With these inputs the list becomes:

```
φημί βίβημι δίδημι τίθημι πίμπλημι ἵλημι ὀνίνημι δάμνημι κρήμνημι πέρνημι πίτνημι πίμπρημι κίχρημι ἵστημι ἄημι ἵημι ὄλλυμι δαίνυμι ὀρέγνυμι πήγνυμι ῥήγνυμι μίγνυμι ὀμόργνυμι ἔργνυμι εἵργνυμι ζεύγνυμι δείκνυμι ὄμνυμι κρεμάννυμι κεράννυμι ζώννυμι ῥώννυμι ὄρνυμι δίδωμι εἶμι σκίδνημι πετάννυμι σβέννυμι στορέννυμι ἕννυμι ἄγνυμι χώννυμι κεδάννυμι σκεδάννυμι κίδνημι κορέννυμι οἴγνυμι χρώννυμι κτίννυμι μείγνυμι εἰμί
```

Putting these in alphabetical order (almost, at least) gives:

```
ἄγνυμι ἄημι βίβημι δάμνημι δίδημι δίδωμι δαίνυμι δείκνυμι εἰμί εἶμι ἕννυμι εἵργνυμι ἔργνυμι ζεύγνυμι ζώννυμι ἵημι ἵλημι ἵστημι κίδνημι κίχρημι κεδάννυμι κεράννυμι κορέννυμι κρεμάννυμι κρήμνημι κτίννυμι μίγνυμι μείγνυμι οἴγνυμι ὄλλυμι ὄμνυμι ὀμόργνυμι ὀνίνημι ὀρέγνυμι ὄρνυμι πέρνημι πήγνυμι πίμπλημι πίμπρημι πίτνημι πετάννυμι ῥήγνυμι ῥώννυμι σβέννυμι σκίδνημι σκεδάννυμι στορέννυμι τίθημι φημί χρώννυμι χώννυμι
```

This seems to be the final list.
If something is missing or shouldn't be on the list, let me know!

Comment: This is great, thanks very much! From your second list, the simplex verbs are: σκίδνημι πετάννυμι σβέννυμι στορέννυμι ἕννυμι ἄγνυμι χώννυμι κεδάννυμι σκεδάννυμι. In the same list there are some compound verbs of which the simplex forms don't seem to appear in the master list for some reason: κίδνημι κορέννυμι οἴγνυμι χρώννυμι κτίννυμι μείγνυμι. Also εἰμί (not the same as εἶμι) is missing. (A couple false positives: κόμμι is not a verb but a noun meaning "gum", and ἠρεμί is an adverb "gently".) With these additions we may well have a complete list!

Comment: @TKR You're welcome and thanks for the help! This was a fun challenge, but I knew I couldn't finish alone with my rudimentary Greek. I updated the answer and put the final list at the start. I hope this is at least very close to a complete list.